# Building Customizable report generation Wizard using asp.net core and EF core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a customizable report engine to a project using asp.net core and EF Core. Any sample or guide please?

Comment: What is `report engine`? What is your expected result?

Comment: a customizable report generating interface.